# Does PF RING linux kernel module have functionality to split the incoming traffic to 3 different devices

Tags: c++, linux-kernel

Currently my c++ program uses PF ring kernel module to read from a 1 Gbps NIC on linux. There is a bottleneck of application that it can not process more than 700 Mbps because it decodes all the headers and maintain some states. 
Now There is an immediate urgency to scale the application to cater 10 Gbps of traffic from a pipe. After making all necessary changes inside my application, it can reach upto 1.2 Gbps.

I have certain queries -

1. Would PF Ring be able to cater 10 Gbps traffic without any packet loss.
2. If yes, is it possible to split the incoming traffic of 10 Gbps to 4 different devices on a round robin fashion using PF Ring module concepts
3. Does anyone have any good reference document of PF Ring.
4. What are the different ways to split the incoming traffic on a particular interface to multiple interface devices in solaris?